# Is it possible to use VueJs 3 in an ES5 only environment via a CDN?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I understand that pretty much all modern browser [support ES6 JavaScript natively](https://caniuse.com/es6) at this point.  And most desktop and mobile browser auto update to the latest version automatically so there is fairly broad ES6 support now.

However, as best I can tell, some android tablets don't make it easy to upgrade the tablet OS or browser and often only support ES5 JavaScript.

Because of this we require that all website code be ES5.  We are currently using VueJs 2.x and use it from a CDN with our ES5 code. And that's been working great even on really old tablets.

We are considering upgrading to VueJS 3.x however it's unclear whether VueJs 3 is available from a CDN as ES5 code.  When I looked in this file:  https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.js I see that it uses the `const` keyword and uses `=>` so it's clearly ES6 code.

So that leaves me wondering if there is a different CDN file for those of us that still want to support older tables with their older browsers.

More specifically: Is it possible to use VueJs 3 in an ES5 only environment via a CDN?

Comment: Looking at their [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/tsconfig.json) they target ES2016, so no probably not unless some third party backported it and made it available on a CDN. Note that with global marketshare of < 5% on desktop and similar numbers on mobile the number of JS libs and frameworks you're going to be able to target the most recent version of is going to quickly trend to zero.

Comment: Unfortunately RhinoJS which is used by HtmlUnit appears to only do ES5 and computed properties are not possible in ES5 and cannot be polyfilled, only a language transform will support it https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/188#issuecomment-1164600517

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

Vue3 relies on `Proxy` for handling reactivity. Even if you can get around some functionalities, adjusting the core code to use Proxies is a non-trivial endeavor, and is, AFAIK, the main reason that Vue3 does and will not support IE11.

You will either need to continue using Vue2, or alternatives like Svelte that can generate ES5 bundles.

Comment: There is maybe a polyfill for proxies?

Comment: @Daniel "For proxy to behave correctly, it needs to be included at compile-time" - this statement is incorrect. At compile time, Proxy is available in compilation environment, i.e. Node, but this doesn't have to do anything with the problem. Proxy should be polyfilled before the app runs, and this is totally possible, regardless of a build in use. The real problem is that proxy polyfill isn't and can't be complete AND compatibility problem is not just proxy but other es6 things. Afaik there's no way to make Vue 3 work in IE11 with polyfills only and no changes in the lib

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for the correction, removed the comment